# Can I refer to current clipboard content as a file?

Tags: devices, clipboard

I'd like to select-and-copy some text to clipboard and then to send it via Bluetooth to my phone. But this requires to open a file to send. Well, I know about programs like `xsel` or `xclip`, but here it goes other way---can I refer to clipboard content as a file so I can actually select it via file requester? Like `/dev/clipboard/primary` or similar?